# Mac OS X screenshot with tagging of front most application

Tags: macos, automator, screen-capture

I would like to automate the filing of screenshots according to which application window was front most when taking a screenshot. I would like to do a hazel rule but I do not have the information of which app was in front when taking the screenshot. Any ideas about application or script?

thank you very much
Hubertus

Comment: What have you done so far? Please add that to your question. Also macOS **itself** is what took the screen shot not the app itself. Was that a typo?

Comment: I changed the typo. Actually I do not advance, as I have no clue how to get the information I want. There is no EXIF info or Finder comment about the active application when taking the screen shot

Comment: I would imagine this could be done in Applescript, a subject I know next to nothing about. But I am not surprised that the screen capture has no info about what is on the screen as it is just a picture of any and all open applications. The Mac doesn't care what the applications are it just takes a picture. You may want to look for Applescript specific discussions/websites and see if you can find someone who is working on this issue, solved it or can assist. Note that the AD community has Applescript experience (not me tho...) but is not going to write it for you...

Comment: As a general rule it's not the _frontmost_ app that takes the screenshot and the taking there of are thru _global system keyboard shortcuts_, and doesn't know or care which app is _frontmost_. I do not have **Hazel**, so I can't help you there. That said, as mentioned by Steve Chambers, here is a line of **AppleScript** _code_ that will get the name of the _frontmost app_, placing it in the `appName` _variable_ for you to work with further with some additional **AppleScript** _code_: `tell application "System Events" to set appName to name of (first process whose frontmost is true)`

Comment: ok that was the solution. I wrote an automator action containing an applescript to get the app name. Automator steps to save it in a variable, make a screenshot and rename this screenshot with app name and date. thanks a lot

Comment: Here’s a more preferred method of getting the frontmost application using AppleScript: `return the name of the application named (path to frontmost application)`. It will always return the correct name and without needing any special permissions.